# Codeigniter: Unable to send emails using php mail()

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, email, smtp

Yesterday I made a contact form with email function. All was working properly because I was using Gmail as protocol.

My problem was that Gmail automatically changes the `from` email to the Gmail account specified. I don't want that. I want to mail from the email specified in the contactform.

I am using a webserver. My site is on http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl

My config/email.php looks like this:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'mail';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset']  = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['newline']  = "\r\n";
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
```

And my configuration for the form looks like:

```
    public function sendmail()
    {
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        $this->email->from($this->input->post('from'), $this->input->post('name'));

        $this->email->to('info@keessonnema.nl');    

        $this->email->subject($this->input->post('subject'));      

        $naam = $this->input->post('name');
        $email = $this->input->post('from');
        $tel = $this->input->post('tel');
        $site = $this->input->post('site');
        $sub = $this->input->post('subject');
        $msg = $this->input->post('message');

        $this->email->message("
        <div id='email'>
        <p><b>Bedrijf:</b> <br/> $naam</p>
        <p><b>Email:</b> <br/> $email</p>
        <p><b>Tel:</b> <br/> $tel</p>
        <p><b>Website:</b> <br/> $site</p>
        <p><b>Onderwerp:</b> <br/> $sub</p>
        <p><b>Toelichting:</b> <br/> $msg</p>
        </div>
        ");

        $success = ('
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);">Uw Email is succesvol verzonden!</div>
        ');

        if($this->email->send())
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Email successvol verzonden.');
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
            die;
            redirect('contact/index');
        }
        else
        {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
```

But this isn't working. It looked like this, and this worked:

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'mypassword';
$confog['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
```

EDIT:

I have this in my php.ini:

> Path to sendmail  /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

When I look at the show_debugger I see:

> Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol:
>   mail

But I get nothing in my mailbox.

Hope someone can help me, telling me what's wrong or what I'm missing.

Comment: Are you on localhost? Do you have an email client installed?

Comment: I am on a webserver so I don't know if I have an email client installed. Gmail worked fine, so

Comment: Where are you specifying the from? Google is using your `smtp_user` email address, because maybe you aren't specifying it?

Comment: Check your hosts rules on sending email. They can be slightly different depending on th host but it should be documented on there help/support pages.

Comment: @We0 I don't want to use Gmail because that changes the `from` email to the gmail user email specified in email.php I will post my config in the controller.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am working in a company with their own domain rules, and the people who have knowledge about it are not here at the moment.